# Django Query Return One Model as Another

Tags: python, django

I couldn't find a similar question (perhaps because I do not know the correct verbiage), but this is my dilemma.  I have two models, one showing a relationship of the other.

I want to be able to compare the 'user_list' and 'friends_list' in the html template so that I can determine whether to not show a user in the "available users" section if a friend relationship already exists.

However, the 'user_list' objects are of the CustomUser model type, and the 'friends_list' objects are of the Friend model type.  How can I return the results of the get_friends() method such that I can exclude these friends from the 'user_list' queryset, preferably by pk so I don't have to worry about string comparisons?

Thank you!

Models.py

```
class CustomUserModel(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # Simplified for brevity
    username = models.CharFiend(_('username'), unique=True)

class Friend(models.Model):
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete.models.CASCADE, related_name='user1')
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete.models.CASCADE, related_name='user2')

    objects = FriendManager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user1', 'user2')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user2)
```

Managers.py

```
class FriendManager(models.Manager):
    def is_friend(self, user1, user2):
        if not user1 or not user2:
            return False
        return super(FriendManager, self).get_queryset().filter(user1=user1).filter(user2=user2).exists()

    def get_friends(self, user):
        return super(FriendManager, self).get_queryset().filter(user1=user)
```

Views.py

```
class UserList(ListView):
    model = get_user_model()
    context_object_name = "object_list"
    template_name = "users.html"

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = get_user(request)
        return super(UserList, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return get_user_model().objects.order_by("-date_joined")

    def get_friends(self):
        if self.user:
            return Friend.objects.get_friends(self.user).order_by("user2")
        return None

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'user_list': self.get_queryset(),
            'friends_list': self.get_friends(),
            'user': self.user
        })
```

Users.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Available Users</h1>
{% for user in user_list %}
    {% if user not in friends_list %} <!-- This is my pain-point -->
        <p>{{ user }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<h1>Friends</h1>
{% for friend in friends_list %}
    <p>{{ friend }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Have you considered building the list of available users in the view and passing it through? You have more flexibility in the view than you do in the template.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I did think about that but still struggled reconciling the Friend.user against the CustomUser.user.  At this point I'm really curious to know if there is an elegant way to make comparisons or conversions between the model classes; though I'm sure I could hack together a solution via list comparisons of the primary ids of both model types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change your query to get `CustomUser`. So the query should be something like `CustomeUser.objects.filter(user2__user1=self.user)` this will give you the `CustomUser`s that are friends with `self.user`. Depending on how you interpret the relation you should also need to query for `CustomUser.objects.filter(user1__user2=self.user)`. These queries should replace your query in the `get_friends()` method of your view.